# Is there anyway to use Google Talk, with my Google Apps account?

Tags: 10.10, google-talk

I have a Google Apps acount where I work at, and we use Google Talk to communicate.

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Should this not be in the webapps site? How is this Ubuntu related?

Comment: Because the question is how to use google talk nativly via a client on Ubuntu, such as Pidgin or Emphathy...

Comment: Gotcha. I would suggest editing the content of the question to suggest what you just described.

Comment: See my answer at 
[This thread discusses similar work with empathy IM Client. ][1]
http://askubuntu.com/questions/105730/google-talk-account-not-working-with-empathy/230514#230514

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a method using Pidgin [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/26072/how-to-setup-a-google-talk-for-your-domain-account-in-pidgin/)

Of course the problem with this method is that you have to install and run Pidgin...

Also I just realized that you can use Empathy as well, it just takes forever for it to log in... you just log in as you normally would with the Google Talk client, username@domain.net then your password under the Google Talk option.

Answer (score 1):

To use Google Talk in Linux you can use some applications listed [here](http://www.google.com/talk/otherclients.html), or you can use the [Google Talk plug-in](http://www.google.com/talk/) for your browser.

Comment: Sorry mate, I tried to upvote you, and broke the system :-(

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this handy trick to do all you can do with google talk, audio/video chatting 
http://tutafuta.com/2011/05/25/how-to-use-gtalk-on-linux-or-mac/

Answer (score 0):

Google talk and Google Apps are from the same stable and use the same Jabbar API to communicate. It does not matter if you have a google.com account or a hosted domain account. Both are equally supported by the following tools:

1. [pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/)
2. [kopete](http://kopete.kde.org/)
3. [empathy](https://live.gnome.org/Empathy)

Just add a jabbar account and fill complete email address, password and enable TLS. Certificate check may fail, so you can set the options accordingly.