# Google Talk account not working with Empathy

Tags: empathy, google-talk

I am setting up Ubuntu. I just got ubuntu installed this morning. I went to set up Empathy with my Google Talk account, but no matter what, it says "Authorization Failed" even though I can very well use my account INCLUDING Google Talk in my web browser. Please help me - I hope this can be fixed.

Comment: Do you use two-factor authentication with your Google Account?

Comment: Try changing your password to a value not containing special characters like `<`, `>` and `&`.

Comment: Are you connecting to the Internet through a proxy? If yes, then that might a possible reason for the failure.

Comment: Let me see if there is a proxy there shouldn't be but you never know... Just for a fact it works on the site so it is either a problem with Ubuntu (easy) or a problem with Google (VERY BAD).

Answer (score 5):

If you have two-factor authentication enabled, you need to create a application specific password. You can do so [here](https://www.google.com/accounts/IssuedAuthSubTokens)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem.
I have had to delete my online google account in Ubuntu (13.04), then delete all authorizations for Ubuntu on my google account > security > manage apps.
Via https://www.google.com/settings/security

Then, I have recreated my online account in Ubuntu with the Google Talk configuration.

Comment: I juste deleted the online account in Ubuntu (13.04) and recreated it. Then it worked. I didn't need to chhange my google.com settings.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration is straightforward by creating a Jabber profile.

- Login ID: *your full e-mail address*
- Password: *your password*

Advanced

- Encryption required (TLS/SSL): *checked*
- Ignore SSL certificate errors: *checked*

Resource

- Priority: 0

Override server settings

- Server: `talk.google.com`
- Port: `5222`

Comment: Please don't recommend to ignore SSL certificate errors. This way you're vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Authorization failed" in Empathy with Google Talk account, just type the keyword in the corresponding entry at the keyring in Ubuntu 12.04. I hope this helps you.